# Rabbitmq: To send same object to multiple endpoints should we use topic based publisher and subscriber OR one conditional subscriber

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We have three different type of objects:
 1. ObjectA
 2. ObjectB

We need to send these object information to three different APIs:
 1. API A - We need to send only ObjectA.
 2. API B - We need to send only ObjectB.
 3. API AB - We need to send ObjectA & ObjectB.

Since these objects will be pushed to our system at very high frequency and need to be processed asynchronously, we have decided to use rabbitmq to push these to respective APIs.

We have two options:

1. Create one consumer: Object will be pushed as NameValueCollection, if its ObjectA, push to API A and API AB. If its ObjectB, push it to API B and API AB.
2. Create separate consumers: Separate consumers for these three and message routed to approariate consumer through routing key i.e. consumerA looking for objects with routing key of ObjectA message, same for consumerB, while consumerAB looking for messages with both routing keys.

   Which is better approach? 2nd looks standard one but first looks simpler and more aligned with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the "producer" should not have to worry about which consumer will end up reading the messages, and should just publish messages to a unique place (an exchange of type *Topic* ) but could use the routing key to flag messages from a given type, for instance : `MyApi.ObjectA` and `MyApi.ObjectB`.

Using appropriate routing keys means that you can completely defer the "routing" to RabbitMQ.

You can then create several queues (one per consumer) :

- consumer A : binding key = `MyApi.ObjectA`
- consumer B : binding key = `MyApi.ObjectB`
- consumer AB : binding key = `MyApi.*`

What it means is that 
- consumer A wil never ever be bothered with messages of type A
- consumer B will never ever be bothered with messages of type B

so if for some reason there are more messages of type A than B, only the related consumers will be impacted. You will also be able to add extra consumers of the specific type, and scale only the part that is needed.

Having separate queues also mean you can more easily control the usage of your queues and know if you may need to scale up.

Comment: Got it. But if consumer need to send some common information to APIs along with object A and object B, we'll need to hit DB/cache twice. Is that correct?  Is there any harm if one consumer de queue different type of messages I. E. ObjectA, objectB or one consumer should de queue just one type of message